# Showing MDI Child - A random form visible only for a millisecond appearing on the screen

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, mdi

I have an MDI form with treeview on the left and form to appear on the right with splitter towards left side. I want to open a form based on the user click on the node within treeview how do I do it properly. The problem is that when I open new form a random one pops up on the screen for a milisecond and then it disappears, and the one that mean to appear is showing straight after.
Here is my code so far:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    CloseAllMdiChildForms();
    if (e.Node.Name == "root")
    {
        CustomerFrm cf = new CustomerFrm();
        cf.Show();
        cf.MdiParent = this;
    }

    //treeView1.MouseClick();
    //if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Level == 0)
    //{
    //    CustomerFrm CF = new CustomerFrm();
    //    CF.ShowDialog();
    //}
}
```

There is a random form visible only for a millisecond appearing on the screen without reason. What's the problem?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: There is a random form visible only for a millisecond appearing on the screen without reason.

Comment: It's because you first Show the form and then set its `MdiParent`. So it flickers; it shows outside the mdi area and then after setting its mdi parent it shows in mdi client area. To solve the problem, it's enough to first set `cf.MdiParent = this;` then call `cf.MdiParent = this;`.

Comment: By the way, I corrected my typo in answer: first set `cf.MdiParent = this;` and then call `cf.Show();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flicker is because you first show the form and then set its `MdiParent`. So it flickers; it shows outside the mdi area and then after setting its `MdiParent` it shows in mdi client area.

To solve the problem, it's enough to first set `cf.MdiParent = this;` and then call `cf.Show();`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the commented code, the event you are looking for is [NodeMouseClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodemouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node.Name == "root")
    {
        CustomerFrm childForm = new CustomerFrm();
        childForm.MdiParent = this;
        childForm.Show();
    }
}
```